# Timeout TCP Connection in HttpClient

Tags: vb.net, post, timeout

I need to configure a TCP connection timeout for a HttpClient. Currently I'm using the normal timeout used for the whole request, but it is not enough to control correctly my application's POSTs.

```
     Using client As New HttpClient()
                Dim bArrayCredentials As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LDAPUser") & ":" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LDAPPass"))
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(bArrayCredentials))
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CDbl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TimeoutResponseLoginTVS")))                   

                client.BaseAddress = New Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("URLLogin"))
                Dim peticion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objPeticion)
                Dim content As New StringContent(peticion, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(page, content).Result
                If IsResponseValid(response.StatusCode) Then
                    Dim result As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                    Return result
                End If

                Return Nothing
            End Using
```

¿Is there any way to configure the TCP connection timeout for a HttpClient?

If the last question is not achiveable ¿Is it possible to configure the TCP connection timeout for a HttpWebRequest?

Comment: this is the correct way of doing it. What is that actual problem?

Comment: In this version I cannot control the connection timeout on its own, only the whole petition timeout. I want to configure it separately.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout to httpclient should be set to 100 seconds by default.
Example set the timeout to 5 minutes:

```
Dim Timeout As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
client.Timeout = Timeout
```